# C# How to select specific values from a JSON-File using JSON-Text-Reader

Tags: c#, json, json.net

im having the following problem:

I am making a programm, where it loads a JSON-File, but i need only 2 specific values. I already installed the Newtonsoft-Extension for the JSON-File-reading.

This is the JSON-File (i replaced the values with "example"):

```
 "installed": [
    {
        "name": "example",
        "homepage": null,
        "source": "example",
        "version": "2.0.5",
        "latest": "2.1.5",
        "latest-status": "example",
        "description": "example",
        "abandoned": false
    },
    {
        "name": "example",
        "homepage": "example",
        "source": "example",
        "version": "v2.11.1",
        "latest": "v2.16.0",
        "latest-status": "semver-safe-update",
        "description": "example",
        "abandoned": false
    },
    {
        "name": "examplename",
        "homepage": "https://example.com",
        "source": "example",
        "version": "v9.8.1",
        "latest": "v9.18.0",
        "latest-status": "semver-safe-update",
        "description": "example",
        "abandoned": false
```

But i only need the "name" + the following Name and the "version" + the following version.

I already tried filtering after "name", but then i just get "name" as output and not the following name. Is it possible to say somethink like "Return me the "name" + name?
Here is the code so far:

```
string fileName = "D:\\Test.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                if (reader.Value.ToString() == "name")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why not create an object with the properties you need and let Json.NET deserialize the property as an array of said object? This seems like you're trying to overcomplicate things to me.

Comment: Other way is Deserialize json as List<Dictionary<string,object>> and fetching data by Key "Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Software
{
     public string name {get; set;}
     public string version {get; set;}
     // list all required properties here...
}


public class Installed
{
     public List<Software> installed {get; set;}
}

public class Foo 
{
    public Installed GetInstalledSoftware(string fileName)
    {
        string json;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Installed>(json);
    }
}
```

If you only want to dump the info to console just call GetInstalledSoftware like this:

```
public void Dump()
{
    var installedSoftware = GetInstalledSoftware("myPath");
    foreach (var software in installedSoftware.installed)
         Console.WriteLine($"{software.name} - {software.version}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @xiluo. That really helped me and after a bit of recoding your solution it is working for me. Cheers :)